# C# SphereCast how to use hitInfo

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a fps game where my character can jump.
I am using a spherecast to know if my character is grounded.
This is what i currently have.

```
    public CapsuleCollider capsuleCollider;
void Update()
{
    if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.up * jumpVelocity;
    }
}
private bool IsGrounded()
{
    float downCheck = capsuleCollider.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f;
    return Physics.SphereCast(capsuleCollider.bounds.center, capsuleCollider.bounds.size.x, Vector3.down, hit, capsuleCollider.bounds.extents.y + extraHeight);
}
```

Have no clue what i have to do with hit.
Can someone help me plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have no clue what i have to do with hit

Whatever you want ;)

See [`Physics.SphereCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) the `hit` is an [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out) parameter, that means it's value will be assigned within the `Physics.SphereCast` method.

You can now either do exactly the same like e.g.

```
private bool IsGrounded(out RayCastHit hit)
{
    var downCheck = capsuleCollider.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f;
    return Physics.SphereCast(capsuleCollider.bounds.center, capsuleCollider.bounds.size.x, Vector3.down, out hit, capsuleCollider.bounds.extents.y + extraHeight);
}
```

Or you seem to anyway not need it so you could just pass in `out var hit` and ignore it further or - there actually exists something in c# for ignoring `out` parameters called [Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/discards) - you can simply pass in `out _` like

```
private bool IsGrounded()
{
    float downCheck = capsuleCollider.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f;
    return Physics.SphereCast(capsuleCollider.bounds.center, capsuleCollider.bounds.size.x, Vector3.down, out _, capsuleCollider.bounds.extents.y + extraHeight);
}
```

That tells the compiler that you don't use that value so you don't even have to take care about the type or name of it.

---

And just as a sidenote: Are you sure you want to do a `SphereCast`? This means you shoot out a sphere and see what it will hit in a certain direction ... Do you rather want to use e.g. a [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html)